# Garbage Collector says it is not concurrent

Tags: .net-core, garbage-collection

I have an ASPNETCore WebAPI with dotnet 6, and in the .csproj I have:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
    <ConcurrentGarbageCollection>true</ConcurrentGarbageCollection>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In my Program.cs:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Server:{System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC} LatencyMode:{System.Runtime.GCSettings.LatencyMode} Concurrent:{GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().Concurrent}");
```

And in the output I see:

```
Server:True LatencyMode:Interactive Concurrent:False
```

Why does it say `Concurent:false`?

Answer (score 0):

Server mode and concurrent default to `true`. There is no need to specify them unless you want to turn it off.

And it's because `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo()` does not return the current settings. You get whatever values the last GC happened to set.

You would need to call GetGCMemoryInfo after a concurrent GC has run, then you would see the expected value.